# AuxKlibEnumerateSystemFirmwareTables returns STATUS_NOT_IMPLEMENTED on Win 10 x64 from a driver built with the Win 10 DDK

Tags: c++, windows, driver

I need access to the ACPI tables from my driver so [AuxKlibEnumerateSystemFirmwareTables](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/jj151548(v=vs.85).aspx) and [AuxKlibGetSystemFirmwareTable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/jj151549(v=vs.85).aspx) are clearly the functions I need.

I call [AuxKlibInitialize](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff540636(v=vs.85).aspx) to start with to initialize the Auxiliary Kernel-Mode Library.

What I really want is the "MCFG" table so I started by trying this.

```
NTSTATUS ntStatus = AuxKlibInitialize();

const char kMcfgHeaderSignature[] = "MCFG";

// Table name is passed little-endian order
ULONG headerSignature = 0;
headerSignature += kMcfgHeaderSignature[3] << 24;
headerSignature += kMcfgHeaderSignature[2] << 16;
headerSignature += kMcfgHeaderSignature[1] << 8;
headerSignature += kMcfgHeaderSignature[0];

ULONG tableSize = 0;
ntStatus = AuxKlibGetSystemFirmwareTable(
   'ACPI',
   headerSignature,
   NULL, // No buffer, just get the size for now.
   0,    // (No buffer size)
   &tableSize
   );

unsigned char * table = new unsigned char[tableSize];

ntStatus = AuxKlibGetSystemFirmwareTable(
   'ACPI',
   headerSignature,
   table,
   tableSize,
   NULL // Don't need the size back.
   );

delete[] table;
```

Walking through the code in a debugger, AuxKlibInitialize succeeds but both calls to AuxKlibGetSystemFirmwareTable return 0xC0000002 which is STATUS_NOT_IMPLEMENTED.

I figured there may be an issue with the specific table I need so I tried to get a list of the tables doing this.

```
NTSTATUS ntStatus = AuxKlibInitialize();

const char kMcfgHeaderSignature[] = "MCFG";

// Table name is passed little-endian order
ULONG headerSignature = 0;
headerSignature += kMcfgHeaderSignature[3] << 24;
headerSignature += kMcfgHeaderSignature[2] << 16;
headerSignature += kMcfgHeaderSignature[1] << 8;
headerSignature += kMcfgHeaderSignature[0];

ULONG sigListSize = 0;
ntStatus = AuxKlibEnumerateSystemFirmwareTables(
   'ACPI',
   NULL,
   0,
   &sigListSize
   );

uint32_t * sigList = new uint32_t[sigListSize/4];

ntStatus = AuxKlibEnumerateSystemFirmwareTables(
   'ACPI',
   reinterpret_cast<void*>(sigList),
   sigListSize,
   NULL
   );

delete[] sigList;
```

Again I got STATUS_NOT_IMPLEMENTED this time from the AuxKlibEnumerateSystemFirmwareTables calls.

I looked around quite a bit to figure out why I could be getting a not implemented error from Windows but found no references of this error from these functions anywhere. It seems to be implemented in the 8.0 DDK and later and supported by Windows Vista and later. I am using the Win 10 DDK and testing on a Win 10 system.

Why is the Auxiliary Kernel-Mode Library returning not implemented errors when getting ACPI information?

UPDATE
This got a lot more strange when I reconfigured the hardware. Now it seems to only return the error when a specific PCIe card is in the system. No idea why Windows would say the function is not implemented depending on what hardware is in the system.

UPDATE 2
It now seems this is a timing issue. Even if I have the card that exposes the failure in the system, if I force the code to run after the system is fully booted it works. So it seems that with some hardware configurations I end up calling the Auxiliary Kernel-Mode Library too early in boot. This is really frustrating because there is no information from MS about when you can safely start calling the Auxiliary Kernel-Mode Library.

Comment: I don't have an answer (sorry), but that's a well put and well researched question. So have an upvote.